# WPF formatting labels with StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application. I have some labels and some datagrids which are bound to some public properties. Some of these properties are numerical values.

In the datagrids I have been using the line below to ensure the values only display two decimal places, which works. However when I use the same line below for my label it appears to have no effect on the display as the number shows to about 9 decimal places. I don't understand why it works for the datagrid but not the label?

```
StringFormat={}{0:0.##}



<Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
       Content="{Binding Obs.Tstat, StringFormat={}{0:0.#}}" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource brushLinFont}" 
       FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

**Updated code**

```
 <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
        Content="{Binding Obs.Tstat}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:0.#}}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource brushLinFont}" 
        FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For label you need to use [**ContentStringFormat**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Label Content="{Binding Obs.Tstat}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:0.##}"/>
```

---

**Reason**:

Label's `Content` property is of type `object` and `StringFormat` is used only when binding property is of type `String`.

If you try your code with TextBlock's `Text` property it will work fine with `StringFormat` because Text property is of type string.

Comment: I see that makes sense why it works in my datagrid then. I have changed my code to use ContentStringFormat however the answer is still showing to many decimal places - is there something else I am missing?

Comment: It works completely fine at my end and only show two digits after decimal values. What's the bound value `Obs.Tstat`?

Comment: Obs.Tstat is of type double and the value being displayed is 1.3536. I've edited my post to show what I have

Comment: You have one exra brace in your ContentStringFormat. It should be `"{}{0:0.#}"` instead of `"{}{0:0.#}}"`. Remove last extra curly brace.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick addition I'd like to post along these lines in case anyone else runs in to it... My application uses localization since it has multi-country support, but we also support user's system settings. We noticed `ContentStringFormat` defaults to your UI culture.

That caused an issue in one of our forms where the user's **machine-specific** decimal places they had configured in windows settings were not respected when you specified the `ContentStringFormat`.

Since the [ContentPresenter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentPresenter.cs) simply takes the string format without the converter culture you could normally specify in the binding , this means that a format of say: `0:N` will only return two decimal places if English is my current UI culture, *even though I have 5 decimals specified on my windows settings*.

In our case we applied some binding overrides to work around this, but mainly just wanted to add this extra bit of info in case anyone else runs in to it ;)