# Append default string to a label in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, label

I need to display Time inside a Li.e. **'20 min'**. My data is stored as integer so **'min'** should be appended. Is there a way to append a default string **'min'** to my bound value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [`Binding.StringFormat` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) to format or append additional information to your data bound value:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat={}{0} min}" />
```

When `Time` has a value of `25`, this renders like so:

[image]

You can also try using `'` marks, but you'll have to leave an initial space:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat=' {0} min'}" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Thanks to @Krishna for the following information:

To use the string format with a `Label` control, you must use the `ContentStringFormat` property instead:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Time}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0} min}" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. However 'min' still doesn't appear.

Comment: Yes it will work with `Label`, `TextBlock`, `TextBox` and any other controls that output text... I'm not sure why it's not working for you... I've just double checked it in a test project and it's working fine for me. Did you look at the linked page on MSDN? You'll see a similar example there.

Comment: I do Content="{ Binding Time, StringFormat={}{0} min}"  and only get a digit showing up on my Label. Odd.

Comment: What data type is `Time` (not that that should make any difference)?

Comment: Just a quick suggestion, you can use ContentStringFormat if it is a label to format your string in xaml

Comment: Changed type from Label to TextBlock and it works well. Still do not understand why Label did not work. Thanks guys!

Comment: Here is some explanation as to why stringformat wont work for a label. Use ContentStringFormat as shown in the link to fix your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/22594967/2746905

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Run` like below

```
<TextBlock><Run Text="{Binding Time}"/><Run Text=" min"/></TextBlock>
```